# React Native Flat List Custom Grid

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I worked with flat lists in React Native but I didn't find out, if it would be possible do make a kind of grid like you can see in the image. How could I do that? (The list is going on and on)

[image: Phone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the solution is to create ItemView for each section and each ItemView will be another FlatList with horizontal scrolling, so basically you will have one external list with vertical scrolling where each item is FlatList with horizontal scrolling customised by index of the external list.

Comment: Thank you, but I think that isn't what I want

Answer (score 0):

with `numColumns` prop, multiple columns can be rendered.

```
<FlatList
          data={listItems}
          numColumns={2}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
          renderItem={ItemView}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
/>
```

checkout this [example](https://snack.expo.io/@nilesh.nvs/cc0576)

Comment: Thanks, but the think is the images does have a different size. (They have to be cuttet by the flat list)

Comment: image wont be having fixed size?? 1st and 2nd image??